# Problema al descargar un Archivo pdf con dompdf, ajax, y php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, dompdf

tengo un sistema cotizador que genera un pdf con la cotizacion y luego puedo descargarlo. El problema esta que cuando intento descargar el primer archivo de la sesion no me lo descarga pero luego si hago un segundo si me deja descargarlo.
Este es el codigo:

```
<?php

use FontLib\Table\Type\head;

require_once 'app/config.php';

//* primero validamos que existan cotizaciones y el parametro $_GET number
if (!isset($_GET['number'])) {
    redirect('index.php?error=invalid_number');
}
//* si no hay cotizacion
$quotes = get_all_quotes();
if (empty($quotes)) {
    redirect('index.php?error=no_quotes');
}

//* buscar el match del folio que buscamos
$quote = get_quote();
$number = trim($_GET['number']);
$empresa = trim($quote['empresa']);

$file = sprintf(UPLOADS . 'coti_%s_' . date('d-m-y') . '_%s.pdf', $empresa, $number);

if (!is_file($file)) {
    // No existe la cotización
    redirect('index.php?error=not_found');
}

//*descarga
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header(sprintf('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=%s', pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME)));
readfile($file);
```

Peticion de AJAX:

```
$("#generate_quote").on("click", generate_quote);
  function generate_quote(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let button = $(this),
      default_text      = button.html(), // "Generar"
      new_text          = "Volver a generar",
      download          = $("#download_quote"),
      vendedor          = $('#vendedor').val(),
      email_vendedor    = $('#email_vendedor').val(),
      division          = $('#division').val(),
      telefono_vendedor = $('#telefono_vendedor').val(),
      cliente           = $("#cliente").val(),
      empresa           = $("#empresa").val(),
      email             = $("#email").val(),
      telefono          = $("#telefono").val(),
      tiempo_entrega    = $("#tiempo_entrega").val(),
      forma_pago        = $("#forma_pago").val(),
      action            = "generate_quote",
      errors            = 0;

    // Validando la acción
    if (!confirm("¿Estás seguro?")) return false;

    // Validando la información
    if (cliente.length < 5) {
      notify(
        "Ingresa un nombre para el cliente por favor (MAS DE 5 CARACTERES)",
        "danger"
      );
      errors++;
    }

    if (empresa.length < 5) {
      notify(
        "Ingresa una empresa válida por favor (MAS DE 5 CARACTERES)",
        "danger"
      );
      errors++;
    }

    if (email.length < 5) {
      notify(
        "Ingresa una dirección de correo válida por favor (MAS DE 5 CARACTERES)",
        "danger"
      );
      errors++;
    }

    if (errors > 0) {
      return false;
    }

    // Petición
    $.ajax({
      url: "ajax.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      cache: false,
      data: {
        action,
        vendedor,
        email_vendedor,
        telefono_vendedor,
        division,
        cliente,
        empresa,
        email,
        telefono,
        tiempo_entrega,
        forma_pago,
      },
      beforeSend: () => {
        $("body").waitMe();
        button.html("Generando...");
      },
    })
      .done((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          notify(res.msg);
          download.attr("href", res.data.url);
          download.fadeIn();
          button.html(new_text);
        } else {
          notify(res.msg, "danger");
          download.attr("href", "");
          download.fadeOut();
          button.html("Reintentar");
        }
      })
      .fail((err) => {
        notify("Hubo un problema con la petición, intenta de nuevo.", "danger");
        button.html(default_text);
      })
      .always(() => {
        $("body").waitMe("hide");
      });
  }
```

codigo en functions.php:

```
function hook_generate_quote()
{
    //*Validar
    if (!isset($_POST['vendedor'] ,$_POST['email_vendedor'], $_POST['division'], $_POST['telefono_vendedor'], $_POST['cliente'], $_POST['empresa'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['telefono'], $_POST['tiempo_entrega'], $_POST['forma_pago'])) {
        json_output(json_build(400, null, 'Parametros incompletos'));
    }
    //* Validar correo
    if ((!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) && (!filter_var($_POST['vendedor_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
        json_output(json_build(400, null, 'Dirección de correo no valida, Revise que esten bien escritos'));
    }

    //* Guardar informacion del cliente
    $client = [
        'vendedor'          => $_POST['vendedor'],
        'email_vendedor'    => $_POST['email_vendedor'],
        'division'          => $_POST['division'],
        'telefono_vendedor' => $_POST['telefono_vendedor'],
        'cliente'           => $_POST['cliente'],
        'empresa'           => $_POST['empresa'],
        'email'             => $_POST['email'],
        'telefono'          => $_POST['telefono'],
        'tiempo_entrega'    => $_POST['tiempo_entrega'],
        'forma_pago'        => $_POST['forma_pago']
    ];

    set_client($client);

    //*cargar cotizacion

    $quote = get_quote();

    if (empty($quote['items'])) {
        json_output(json_build(400, null, 'No hay conceptos en la cotización'));
    }

    $module = MODULES . 'pdf_template';
    $html = get_module($module, $quote);
    $filename = 'coti_' . $quote['empresa'] . '_' . date('d-m-y') . '_' . $quote['number'];
    $download = sprintf(URL . 'pdf.php?number=%s', $quote['number']);
    $quote['url'] = $download;

    //* generar pdf y guardar en el servidor
    if (!generate_pdf(UPLOADS . $filename, $html)) {
        json_output(json_build(400, null, 'Hubo un problema al generar la corización.'));
    }

    json_output(json_build(200, $quote, 'Cotización generada con éxito.'));
}

function generate_pdf($filename = null, $html, $save_to_file = true)
{
    //nombre del archivo
    $filename = $filename === null ? time() . '.pdf' : $filename . '.pdf';


    $pdf = new Dompdf();
    $pdf->setPaper('A4');
    $pdf->loadHtml($html);
    $pdf->render();

    if ($save_to_file) {
        $output = $pdf->output();
        file_put_contents($filename, $output);
        return true;
    }
    $pdf->stream($filename);
    return true;
}

function get_all_quotes()
{
    return $quotes = glob(UPLOADS . 'coti_*.pdf');
}

function redirect($route)
{
    header(sprintf('Location: %s', $route));
    exit;
}
```

me percate de que esta entrando en el siguiente if

```
 if (!is_file($file)) {
    // No existe la cotización
    redirect('index.php?error=not_found');
}
```

pero no entiendo porque si el archivo se esta generando correctamente, y solo pasa con el primero que hago al iniciar el navegador.

necesito ayuda pueden probar el sistema en el siguiente link: discoverycenterpa.net/sicot-1

Comment: En el título de la pregunta mencionas AJAX, pero en el código no incluiste la petición. Probablemente estás intentando descargar antes de que acabe de generarse el archivo. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código de la petición AJAX y cómo generas el PDF (no todo el código, solo lo básico).

Comment: @triby ya agregue la peticion a ajax, y lo que comentas no... Eh revisado que el archivo se genere y se guarde en el servidor, efectivamente se genera y se guarda pero no se descarga. Esto solo ocurre con el primer archivo que se genere, con los proximos que hagas no.